# Fragment Viewpager Progress dialog

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-progressbar

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) { 
            new LoadGlobalNews().execute();
        }

    }
```

Am using the above method in fragment class to execute the async task, my problem is that every time a swipe away from the fragment, and return the async task is re executed any other alternative

Comment: increment the count whenever the method is called.  Now call the AsyncTask when the count is only 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit`.

[From the docs](http://bit.ly/1epmwHF):

> Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the
>   current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this
>   limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

**Example**

```
mYourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(mYourPagerAdapter.getCount());
```

*Update*

```
private boolean mLoadedNews;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser && !mLoadedNews) {
        new LoadGlobalNews().execute();
        mLoadedNews = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: my reason for using the `setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) ` is because the progress dialog of the other fragments where all popping up when the application loads,so i decided to execute the async task when the fragment is visible this means, every the fragment is visible the async task will reload which i dont want. any way i can prevent that

Comment: @RuyongaDan The easiest way I could think of is to add an extra condition when checking `isVisibleToUser`, I made an edit to demonstrate.

Comment: this solves my main problem but creates another, my content from the second fragment is loaded into the first fragment and this leaves it blank and content of fragment one not displayed. any idea why.